# Styled components onClick rotate element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm trying to add a rotation to an element when clicked. Each time I want to click on the element the element should rotate. I'm rotating the element using CSS transform property. Bellow is my styled component:

```
const IconButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  ${({ rotate }) => rotate && `transform: rotate(360deg)`};
`;
```

And I have the React component that renders the element and has the `onClick` event:

```
const IconButtonContainer = () => {
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () =>
    setRotate(
      (prevState) => ({ rotate: !prevState.rotate }),
      () => console.log(this.state.rotate)
    );

  return (
    <IconButtonWrapper rotate={rotate} onClick={handleClick}>
      <IconButton />
    </IconButtonWrapper>
  );
};
```

When I click the first time everything works as expected, but when I click the second time, doesn't work anymore. I feel I should return to default state `rotate: false` after the transition, but how do I do that in styled components?

Here is a link to a working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/onclick-rotate-hooks-forked-45o6j?file=/src/index.js:371-729)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically `rotate` is already a **boolean** so `prevState` should be a **boolean** as well. Also you were trying to set an object to the `rotate` state value instead of a simple **boolean**.

Based on that you only need to negate `prevState` and not `prevState.rotate` as:

```
setRotate(prevState => !prevState)
```

See the code modification from `!prevState.rotate` to `!prevState`.

Also suggested read is [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). It's a bit different than class components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
const handleClick = () => setRotate(!rotate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solving by changing the code of `handleClick` to:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "./styles.css";

const IconButton = () => <button>Icon</button>;

const IconButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  ${({ rotate }) => rotate && `transform: rotate(360deg)`};
`;

const IconButtonContainer = () => {
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setRotate((prevState) => (!prevState ));
  return (
    <IconButtonWrapper rotate={rotate} onClick={handleClick}>
      <IconButton />
    </IconButtonWrapper>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IconButtonContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`prevState` already has the latest value of `rotate` but you were converting it to an object. `setRotate((prevState) => (!prevState ));` will do.